# Facebook API : "The publish_likes feature is disabled for this application"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I get this error when trying to post a like on a post done by a user with Facebook Graph API and using the application token subscribed by that user. The permissions bound to the application are "publish_actions", "publish_stream". 
According to the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/
such permissions should also be enough to post a like. (posting a feed works anyway)
How to match the missing feature with the permissions exposed on facebook documentations?

Comment: It works when i proceed by replacing the application token by the usertoken of the people triggering the likes, curl -F access_token=USERTOKENOFTHEPOPLETHATLIKES graph.facebook.com/POSTAFAFRIEND/likes --> true

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "publish_actions"? See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes/#publishing

Comment: Yes publish_actions is selected.

Comment: I don't test with opengraph but with graph api https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/

Comment: I have added publish_actions in user/friends permissions. It was only on extended permissions. I don't have any more the error in title but instead i get "You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action"